# Two Problems in view code: a)- fetch and view image from database not working b)- onchange function not working

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

Below given code for view:

The code for insert is 100% correct and working as desired (uploading image and putting into desired folder). Error is with the code for view.

Problem starts with this code.

a. When i am viewing, the images are not displayed. The box, with broken icon for image, appears. I want to appear image in this box by fetching image from database.

b. In "Genre" when i am changing the genre, nothing happens. I want that if i choose "Action/Mission" genre then all games with the genre "Action/Mission" should appears on changing and if i choose "Racing" genre then all games with the genre "Racing" should appears onchanging.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_jumpMenu(val){
var abc = document.getElementById(jumpMenu).value;
  if (abc == "Action/Mission"){
      return abc;}
  if (abc == "Racing"){
      return abc;}
  else { return false; }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="216">
  <tr>
    <td width="46">Name</td>
    <td width="46"><form name="form" id="form">
        <select name="jumpMenu" id="jumpMenu" onChange="MM_jumpMenu(this.value)">
          <option value="">--Select Genre--</option>
          <option value="Action/Mission">Action</option>
          <option value="Racing">Racing</option>
        </select>
    </form></td>
    <td width="61">Image 1</td>
    <td width="63">Image 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <?php
$abc=mysql_query("select * from games order by game");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($abc))
{
?>
    <td><?php echo $row['game']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['genre']; ?></td>
    <td><img src="admin\images/<?php echo $row['image1'].'.jpg'; ?>" height="50" width="50" /></td>
    <td><img src="admin\images/<?php echo $row['image1'].'.jpg'; ?>" height="50" width="50" /></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: "admin\images/" --> "admin\images\" try this :

Comment: echo the image url and paste it in browser , them check if you are able to access that image in browser ,  i think the problem here would be wrong Image path

Comment: image is in my local hard disk, i uploaded it from various folder to a specified folder in insert query.

Comment: @$image1=$_POST['image1'];
@$pic1="admin\images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"];
@move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],$pic1);

Comment: can you please paste the code that you used to save the image details to db too? I think you have saved the image name with extension to database. And here in view page, attaching .jpg again. That is for image1.jpg it may be resulting image1.jpg.jpg

Comment: Also it is better to save the image extension in the database since there may be PNG, GIF or some other image format. Not just JPG all the time.

Comment: This is the code for uploading the image      @$image1=$_POST['image1'];

@$pic1="admin\images/".$_FILES["image1"]["name"];

@move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image1"]["tmp_name"],$pic1);